# How to convert NumberLong to Date in MongoDB's shell?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am storing unix timestamp as MongoDB's `NumberLong` type  (millisecond) , how to convert to human readable date string in the Mongo shell?

Answer (score 4):

For my own future reference (and incorporating the other answers):

```
db.mycollection.aggregate([
  {$match:{"userId":"d1792d83-d854-44d5-9jc5-e3e20435958b"}},
  {$project:{newDate:Date("$numberLongDate")}}
])
```

Comment: On second view, this doesn't seem to work.  It's returning the same Date for every `$numberLongDate`.

Comment: Here's the fix: `newDate:{$add: [new Date("1970-01-01"), "$numberLongDate"]}`.

Comment: Hi fwc, I've been trying to emulate your code above and when I run it it returns Nulls in all the new date columns. Can you see what I'm doing wrong? ```db.mycoll.aggregate([
  {$project:{newDate: {$add: [new Date("1970-01-01"), "$numberLongDate"]}}}])```

Comment: Tough to tell, $numberLongDate needs to be the name of your date field maybe?

Answer (score 3):

```
NumberLong(123123123123131).toNumber().toString()
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm using expressions like that:

```
>Date(NumberLong("1397051113715"));
```

it will be work too.

Answer (score 1):

I converted unix NumberLong epoch to Date using:

```
new Date(1413382500151)
```

Comment: 1413382500151 is just a `Number` type, not a `NumberLong`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to cast it to a string, for example

```
 >var a = db.collection.findOne({name :"zengse"},{"createDate":1,_id:0})
 > a.createDate
 NumberLong("1575741914380")
 > var b = a.createDate.toNumber()
 > new Date(b)
 ISODate("2019-12-07T18:05:14.380Z")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the `NumberLong` value directly to the `Date` constructor function if you call it with `new` and then call `toString()` on it to convert it to a human readable string:

```
> var n = NumberLong('1397051113715')
> (new Date(n)).toString()
Wed Apr 09 2014 08:45:13 GMT-0500 (CDT)
```

But you should strongly consider storing those timestamps as `Date`s in MongoDB for more flexibility.