# Find and Delete documents in MongoDB using a Windows GUI tool

Tags: mongodb, nosql

Okay, I'm a SQL Server based DBA, but there's a biz-critical app that uses MongoDB as a core component, and the problem is that it's grown too large.  (The "large-ness" isn't critical yet, I'm trying to be proactive!)

Specifically, it has a "message log" collection which is over 400 GB, where the date-stamp is actually stored as a 2-element array [Int64, Int32], the 0th element being some measure of time (and the 1th element is just always '0').

So for example, a document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55ef63618c782e0afcf346cf"),
    "CertNumber" : null,
    "MachineName" : "WORKERBEE1",
    "DateTime" : [ 
        NumberLong(635773487051900000), 
        0
    ],
    "Message" : "Waited 00:00:30.0013381 to get queue lock: Specs to verify",
    "ScopeStart" : false
}
```

And just because 2 is better than 1, another example document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55ef63618c782e0afcf323be"),
    "CertNumber" : null,
    "MachineName" : "WORKERBEE2",
    "DateTime" : [ 
        NumberLong(635773487056430453), 
        0
    ],
    "Message" : "Waited 00:00:30.0012345 to get queue lock: Specs to verify",
    "ScopeStart" : false
}
```

I need to figure out two things:

1. What the heck does that "DateTime" really mean?  It's not Unix Epoch time (seconds nor milliseconds); and even if I strip off the trailing 0's, it represents (in millis) 6/20/2171, so, unless we're building a time machine here, it makes no sense.  If I strip off the last 6 digits, it means 2/23/1990, but even that doesn't seem likely, as this application has only existed since the early 2000's. (AFAIK)
2. Assuming we figure out #1, can we use some kind of command to remove (delete) all documents in the collection that are *older than*, say, 1/1/2016?

Again, I'm a SQL guy, so try to explain using analogs in that vein, e.g. "this is like your WHERE clause" and such.

PS: Yes, I read thru questions such as [Find objects between two dates MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943222) and [How do I convert a property in MongoDB from text to date type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900674) , but so far nothing has jumped out at me.

Comment: Answer to Q1: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22964199/how-to-convert-numberlong-to-date-in-mongodbs-shell

Comment: Nice tip; still not applicable.  As I said, the number actually makes no sense as a standalone date/time, even in milliseconds.

Comment: Okay, got an answer finally for #1: the array is basically a "raw" representation of the C# `DateTimeOffset` datatype.  [0] element represents "ticks" - 100-nanosecond intervals since 12 midnight on 1/1/0001.  [1] element is the timezone offset ("0" in this case since it's UTC).  That's why it makes no sense to Unix/Epoch time converters!

Comment: The "friendly" interpretation of those 2 sample datetimeoffset values is 9/8/2015 10:38:25 PM give or take some milliseconds.  The full answer will involve creating an index in the mongo collection and attempting to delete documents by referencing the field.  TBD...